# getting django Url template tag to return something useful:throws reverse error

Tags: python, django, django-templates

trying to use the Django `{%url %}` template tag and keep failing.
the view is defined in sitename/transfers/views.py (where transfers is the django app name):

```
def description_ListView(requesst,**kwargs):

    template_name = 'transfers/description.html'

    o = get_list_or_404(Transfer, description =kwargs['description'])
    #print ('o:',o)
    context_object_name = "transfer_name_list" 
    return render_to_response(template_name,{context_object_name:o,'description':kwargs['description']})
```

(yes, I DO know that this code is a little strange. working on making this more generic and caught in the middle with this annoying problem)

and the url is mapped in transfers/urls.py

```
url(r'^description/(?P<description>[\w ]+)/$',
                           'transfers.views.description_ListView',
                           name = 'description_url')
```

and in the tag:
    {% url "description_url" "blabla" %}
also tried:
    {% url "transfers.views.Description_ListView" description = "blabla" %}

the error message:

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '"description_url"' with arguments '(u'blabla',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

or when i Tried using the `as somename` syntax and calling it like this: `{{somename}}. just failed silently and didn't produce anything.

where I also tried importing the Description_ListView from the views and using it directly, didn't help.

Also, following the advice of numerous answers on this subject in various SO questions I changed to double quotes around the view, and reverted to using the url name instead of view but neither helped.

I'll be glad for any help with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need quotes. Try:

```
{% url description_url "blabla" %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns

Comment: thanks @dannyroa now everything works ok when I hard code "blabla" but when I replace it with modelname.property which contains unicode text I keep on getting the reverse error